# Why is the title of "Le Morte d'Arthur" in French if the book is in English?

Tags: title, arthurian-legend, le-morte-darthur, thomas-malory

*Le Morte d'Arthur*, often considered the first English novel, is an early version of the story of Camelot. The book is according, to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Morte_d%27Arthur), written in Middle English. Why, then, is the title of the book in French?

Comment: [Relevant link.](https://www.shmoop.com/morte-d-arthur/title.html) Also, I think in Malory's time French was still the language of the nobility in England?

Comment: @Rand al'Thor—I'd guess most of them actually spoke English by then, but French was still the [legal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_French) of England when Mallory wrote, and it was still more prestigious. And how hard is it to understand the title "Le Morte d'Arthur"?

Answer (score 10):

We don't know very much about the life of Thomas Malory, but it is clear that *Le Morte Darthur* draws on French sources. For example, in "Capitulum tercium" (in the version printed by Caxton, which is available at the [University of Michigan](http://name.umdl.umich.edu/MaloryWks2)), Malory writes (emphasis mine),

> Soo in the grettest chirch of london whether it were Powlis or not the **Frensshe booke** maketh no mencyon

*Le Morte Darthur* makes frequent references to "the Frensshe book". According to scholars, the sources used by Mallory include the following, not all of which are actually in French:

- The "Alliterative *Morthe Arthure*, a 14th-century poem in English, which probably used the 12th-century [*Roman de Brut*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_de_Brut) as a source. In spite of the French titles, both *Morthe Arthure* and *Roman de Brut* are in English.
- The *Suite du Merlin* (also known as the *Huth Merlin* because it is contained in a manuscript at the British Library that is also known as the ["Huth MS"](https://www.bl.uk/catalogues/illuminatedmanuscripts/record.asp?MSID=6730)), which is also in English. See [Prose Merlin: Introduction](https://d.lib.rochester.edu/teams/text/conlee-prose-merlin-introduction) by John Conlee.
- The prose Vulgate *Queste del Saint Graal* (see also [Lancelot-Grail, also known as Vulgate Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lancelot-Grail) on Wikipedia).
- The French Vulgate *Morte Artu*.
- The 15th-century stanzaic *Le Morte Arthur* (in English).

Most (or all) of the Arthurian materials in French and English literature were influenced by the 12th-century French poet [Chrétien de Troyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chr%C3%A9tien_de_Troyes). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Norman_language) also notes that

> Private and commercial correspondence was carried out in Anglo-Norman or Anglo-French from the 13th to the 15th century though its spelling forms were often displaced by continental spellings. Social classes other than the nobility became keen to learn French: manuscripts containing materials for instructing non-native speakers still exist, dating mostly from the late 14th century onwards.

So Malory probably chose a French title for two reasons: French sources and familiarity with either French or Anglo-French in part of the English population.

Sources not linked or listed above:

- Stephen Coote: *The Penguin Short History of English Literature*. London: Penguin, 1993. (Page 50)
- Margaret Drabble (editor): *The Oxford Companion to English Literature*. Revised edition. Oxford: Oxford University Press, 1995.